# Flask-RESTful how to add_resource and pass it non-global data

Tags: python, flask

In the **[Flask-RESTful](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)** example application **[posted here](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#full-example)**, the `TODOS` collection is a global variable.

After the `Todo` **Resource** is registered:

```
api.add_resource(Todo, '/todos/<string:todo_id>')
```

The `Todo` methods access the global `TODOS` variable when web requests are processed.

Instead, I want to instantiate the API within a class and pass a `TODOS` collection that is a class variable rather than a global variable.

When using **Flask-RESTful**, what is the proper way to allow methods in a **Resource** class to gain access to a variable provided by the calling class without using global variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I didn't understand you the first time, You can just use a `classmethod` to construct your API. Then add it as a resource

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.restful import Api

class SomeApi(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return self.response

    @classmethod
    def make_api(cls, response):
        cls.response = response
        return cls


class KillerApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Flask()
        app_api = Api(self.app)
        MyApi = SomeAPI.make_api({"key": "value"})
        app_api.add_resource(MyApi, "/api/path")

    def run(self)
        self.app.run()


KillerApp().run()
```

Comment: I corrected the variable name in the question to match the example linked to. For your sample, the question I have is how you would define `TODOS` inside `KillerApp` and then allow `SomeApi` to access it, rather than `TODOS` being a global variable.

Comment: @Greg it seems it me that cls is a class object rather than an instance, right? if so, it makes sense that cls.response creates a static variable on the class. but in you example i see that the get method returns self.response which is a variable on the instance itself... can you explain? i'm kinda new to python. thanks!

Comment: @danfromisrael you don't necessarily have to use a classmethod. But you have the option of using them as a constructor compared to `__init__`. It's an either or situation, and from what the user was asking me I decided to use a classmethod because it fit more within their solution bias

Answer (score 5):

`add_resource` accepts two arguments, `resource_class_args` and `resource_class_kwargs`, used to pass arguments to the constructor.  ([source](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/intermediate-usage.html#passing-constructor-parameters-into-resources))

> So you could have a Resource:

```
from flask_restful import Resource

class TodoNext(Resource):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # smart_engine is a black box dependency
        self.smart_engine = kwargs['smart_engine']

    def get(self):
        return self.smart_engine.next_todo()
```

> You can inject the required dependency into TodoNext like so:

```
smart_engine = SmartEngine()

api.add_resource(TodoNext, '/next',
    resource_class_kwargs={ 'smart_engine': smart_engine })
```

Answer (score 0):

based on @Greg answer I've added an initialization check in the **init** method:

creating and calling Todo Resource class for flask-restful api:

```
todo = Todo.create(InMemoryTodoRepository())
api.add_resource(todo, '/api/todos/<todo_id>')
```

The Todo Resource class:

```
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Resource
from server.ApiResources.DTOs.TodoDTO import TodoDTO
from server.Repositories.ITodoRepository import ITodoRepository
from server.Utils.Exceptions import InvalidInstantiationError
from server.Utils.GeneralUtils import member_exists


class Todo(Resource):
    """shows a single todo item and lets you delete a todo item
        use the 'create' class method to instantiate the class
    """
    def __init__(self):

        if not member_exists(self, "todo_repository", of_type=ITodoRepository):
            raise InvalidInstantiationError("Todo", "todo_repository", "ITodoRepository", "create")

        self._parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self._parser.add_argument('task', type=str)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, todo_repository):
        """
        :param todo_repository: an instance of ITodoRepository
        :return: class object of Todo Resource
        """
        cls.todo_repository = todo_repository
        return cls
```

the member_exists helper methods:

```
 def member_exists(obj, member, of_type):
        member_value = getattr(obj, member, None)

        if member_value is None:
            return False

        if not isinstance(member_value, of_type):
            return False

        return True
```

and the custom exception class:

```
class InvalidInstantiationError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, origin_class_name, missing_argument_name, missing_argument_type, instantiation_method_to_use):

        message = """Invalid instantiation for class '{class_name}':
                  missing instantiation argument '{arg}' of type '{arg_type}'.
                  Please use the '{method_name}' factory class method""" \
            .format(class_name=origin_class_name,
                    arg=missing_argument_name,
                    arg_type=missing_argument_type,
                    method_name=instantiation_method_to_use)

        # Call the base class constructor with the parameters it needs
        super(InvalidInstantiationError, self).__init__(message)
```

Thus, trying to use the default constructor will end up in getting this exception:

**server.Utils.Exceptions.InvalidInstantiationError: Invalid instantiation for class 'Todo':
                  missing instantiation argument 'todo_repository' of type 'ITodoRepository'.
                  Please use the 'create' factory class method**

edit: this can be useful for using dependency injection with flask-restful api Resource classes (with or without IoC)

edit 2:

we can even go cleaner and add another help function (ready to import):

```
def must_have(obj, member, of_type, use_method):
        if not member_exists(obj, member, of_type=of_type):
            raise InvalidInstantiationError(obj.__class__.__name__,
                                            member,
                                            of_type.__name__,
                                            use_method)
```

and then use it in the constructor like that:

```
from server.Utils.GeneralUtils import must_have

class Todo(Resource):

    def __init__(self):

        must_have(self, 
                  member="todo_repository", 
                  of_type=ITodoRepository, 
                  use_method=Todo.create.__name__)
```