# Flask-RESTful and Kivy

Tags: python, class, kivy, flask-restful

I am using Flask-RESTful together with Kivy. Flask-RESTful api for resource routing and Kivy for the TFT GUI. Both are class based: Kivy's main app `class Touch(App)` and the restful api's `class Load(Resource)`.

```
class Load(Resource):
    @auth.login_required
    def post(self):
        data = request.json
        # call handle(data)


class Touch(App):
    api.add_resource(Load, '/load')
    def handle(data):
        # do something with data
```

I would like to use a method inside the `class Touch(App)` for the routing. I have checked the [flask-restful documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073952/flask-restful-how-to-add-resource-and-pass-it-non-global-data) but have not found an example of a method based resource. Must  it be a class based resource?

Comment: According to the [flask-restful.readthedocs.io](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) documentation it is possible to add a class name of the resource only. It seems that a method name is out of the question.

Comment: I could not find a way to use a method or jump classes. Inter-process communication is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask-RESTful and Kivy can work together as two separate processes. The routing stays under the Flask process which passes the request to the Kivy process using  [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).

**SCRIPT:**
In this script FLASK process fetches a "load" request in json format and passes it to the KIVY process. The script works with Python2.7 and Kivy 1.10.0.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# kivy modules first, if not Kivy may cause problems
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
kivy.require('1.10.0')

# common modules
import sys
import os
import time
import signal
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue

# Flask modules
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource

# wsgi (Web Server Gateway Interface) modules
import eventlet
from eventlet import wsgi

# json modules
import json, ast

# async server setup
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

# global variables
data_json = None

def start_Flask(q):
    print("Starting Flask...")
    q.put([42, None, 'hello'])      # some random initial value
    wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 5000)), app)   # deploy server

def signal_handler(signal, frame):  # process terminator
    print " CTRL + C detected, exiting ... "
    exit(0)

# api resource classes ###############################################
class Load(Resource):
    def post(self):
        data = request.json
        package = ("Load", data)    # create tuple
        q.put(package)  # put tuple into queue

# setup the Api resource routing here ################################
api.add_resource(Load, '/load')

# kivy gui classes ###################################################
# main screen        
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name="MAIN SCREEN"
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class My_Gui(App):
    MainScreenTitle = "MainScreen title"
    MainScreenLabel = "MainScreen label"
    MessageButtonEnter = "GO"
    MessageButtonExit = "EXIT"

    def cancel(self):
        print "load cancelled by user"

    def exit(self):
        print "exiting..."
        p1.terminate()
        exit(1)

    def enter(self):
        print "getting a queue element"
        try:
            if q.empty() == False:
                package = q.get()   # retrieve package from queue
                print("got the package")
                print(package)
        except:
            print "the queue is empty"  

    def build(self):
        sm = Builder.load_string("""

ScreenManager
    MainScreen:
        size_hint: 1, .7
        auto_dismiss: False
        title: app.MainScreenTitle       
        title_align: "center"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Label:
                text: app.MainScreenLabel
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                spacing: 10
                size_hint: 1, .5
                Button:
                    text: app.MessageButtonEnter  # start app
                    on_press:
                        app.enter()
                Button:
                    text: app.MessageButtonExit  # exit app
                    on_press:
                        app.exit()
        """)

        return sm


# main #################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':

    #CTRL+C signal handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

    q = Queue()

    global p1
    p1 = Process(target=start_Flask, args=(q,)) # assign Flask to a process
    p1.daemon = True
    p1.start()  #launch Flask as separate process
    My_Gui().run()   # run Kivy app
```